# How to pass a TCL pipe channel to gpg --passphrase-fd?

Tags: tcl, gnupg

Is it possible to pass a tcl pipe channel to a `gpg --passphrase-fd`?

```
;# $word is a pipe channel opened by pipe (tcl 8.5)
package require pipe;
;#
set fd [open "|gpg -d -q --no-options --batch --passphrase-fd $word $file" "r"]
```

Answer (score 1):

From `man gpg`:

> **`--passphrase-fd n`**
>
> Read the passphrase from file descriptor n. *If you use 0 for n, the
>           passphrase will be read from stdin.*

So I set to value of `--passphrase-fd` to `0` and passed the content of the pipe through the stdin channel to gpg, i.e.

```
set fd [open "|echo [gets $word] | gpg -d -q --no-options --batch --passphrase-fd 0 $file" "r"]
```

Comment: You don't need the echo: `set fd [open |[list gpg -d -q --no-options --batch --passphrase-fd 0 $file << [gets $word]] "r"]` (and that way of writing `|[list …]` is the recommended pattern for building subcommand pipelines; the syntax is a bit screwy).

Comment: Thanks for comment; And one more question; can we guarantee that in this case the value of [gets $word] will not be displayed if I do 'ps'?.